# TradingView - How to copy label text from the chart?

Tags: tradingview-api

I want to copy label text from the chart. How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: If you don't have the access to the indicator's source code - there is no way, only manually re-type the content of the label.

Comment: @e2e4 This is my own pinescript. In that case, is there any way i can copy the text to clipboard.